# Replace phrases in string that aren't all letters Pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas series

```
pd.Series({'products':['deskjet 2620 all in one wireless inkjet printer', 'z3700 wireless optical mouse white' ]})
```

I want to replace all the words that aren't alphabetic from beginning to end. I want the output

```
pd.Series({'products':['deskjet all in one wireless inkjet printer', ' wireless optical mouse white' ]})
```

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: do you want  to save lists in items?

Answer (score 0):

```py
# function to check if number or character
def replace_nums(x):
    no_digits=""
    for i in x:
        if not i.isdigit():
            no_digits+=i


    return no_digits

# eg series
exdict = {'Geeks' : '10abc', 
        'for' : '204f5', 
        'geeks' : '30rew'} 


ser = pd.Series(exdict) 

# apply function to series
ser = ser.apply(replace_nums)
```

Output

```
Geeks    abc
for        f
geeks    rew
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method you can use if you want. Tell me how the speed compares to other methods you come across. Also, this one may be a little bit more pedantic. I will work on one that uses numpy exclusively so it is faster.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

unclean = pd.Series({'products':['deskjet 2620 all in one wireless inkjet printer', 'z3700 wireless optical mouse white']})
clean = pd.Series({'products':['deskjet all in one wireless inkjet printer', ' wireless optical mouse white']})

convert = lambda product: list(filter(lambda good_val: len(set([str(i) for i in good_val]).intersection(set([str(i) for i in range(10)]))) < 1,product))

edited = unclean.apply(lambda val: [' '.join(convert(i.split())) for i in val])

print(unclean.values)
print(edited.values)
```

out:

```
[list(['deskjet 2620 all in one wireless inkjet printer', 'z3700 wireless optical mouse white'])]
[list(['deskjet all in one wireless inkjet printer', 'wireless optical mouse white'])]
```

Comment: Hey @user147529, do you think you can provide some feedback on whether any of these answers worked for you? If you have any questions about the code, just comment here.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out. My dataset wasn't too big. I haven't tried the other answers, but what I've got is good

```
import re

df = pd.DataFrame({'products':['deskjet 2620 all in one wireless inkjet printer', 'z3700 wireless optical mouse white']})

regex = re.compile(r'^[a-z]+$')

df['products_clean'] = [' '.join([j for j in i if regex.match(j)]) for i in df['products'].str.split(' ')]

df
```